# sed replace is not replacing anything

Tags: sed

```sh
sed -i 's/#DirectoryIndex index.html/#DirectoryIndex index.php /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf'
```

which gives out the error

> sed: -e expression #1, char 57: unknown option to `s'

I am trying to replace index.html with index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the string before the filename. And you missed the closing `/`.

```bash
sed -i 's/#DirectoryIndex index.html/#DirectoryIndex index.php/' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Comment: Note that the replace will not make much difference since the line is commented out.